# VC 2015 U3 - ASSERT crashes the application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, mfc

VS 14.0.25431.01 Update 3

Windows 10 - 10.0.10240 Build 10240

Steps:

1. Create a new MFC application.
2. Add `ASSERT( 0 )`, in `CAboutDlg::CAboutDlg`, for instance.
3. Build debug version.
4. Run without debugging (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>).
5. Click About -> The program is silently **ABORTED**
6. Start debugging (<kbd>F5</kbd>)
7. Click About -> **Breakpoint dialog**.

Microsoft has closed the bug as "by design": *"Based upon review of the information provided, we have resolved this issue as "By Design". We cannot identify anything here that is unexpected behavior."*

Works fine with Win7.

I am looking for a workaround.

**[EDIT]**
I've found that `__acrt_get_developer_information_policy()` is returning `developer_information_policy_none` instead of expected `developer_information_policy_ui` (see `common_show_message_box` in `crtmbox.cpp`), but I have no clue on how to change it.

**[EDIT]** See this [link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3107058/assert-crashes-the-application-when-run-without-debugging) and this [one](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3115985/common-show-message-box-bug), at Microsoft Connect.

**[EDIT]** The latest [Windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) has fixed the problem on my machines. All credit goes to cubee_72 (MS account).

**[EDIT]** The latest SDK solved the problem for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, only. If the debugger is present, still the breakpoint dialog, instead of the assert dialog, is displayed.

**[EDIT 2017-11-20]** MS has deleted my bug reports.

Thank you.

Comment: sorry, forget my comment. What kind of crash ? Could you elaborate a bit ?

Comment: Could you detail how exactly (with what options) you create the MFC application ? I could not reproduce this with the default options (same Visual Studio version as you but on Windows 7). Here it always asserts.

Comment: @MichaelWalz It does not crash on Windows 7. The system terminates the application. You will no longer see it in task manager. We get the same behavior with freshly installed VS.

Comment: So on Windows 7 it doesn't behave as expected either ? Please elaborate your question (see my previous comment).

Comment: When it asserts in the debugger there should be a popup dialog that allows you debug or ignore the assertion.

Comment: @MichaelWalz No. On Windows 7 it works as expected. See the question. There is no additional detail beside what I listed in question. It is that simple.

Comment: @drescherjm "...there should be a popup dialog" Yes; instead, it crashes.

Comment: A failed assertion calls [__debugbreak](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f408b4et.aspx). This causes, whatever is entered as the `debugger` in the Image Execution Options to get launched (see [How to: Launch the Debugger Automatically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed(v=vs.100).aspx)). You should verify that you don't have a bogus entry there.

Comment: @IInspectable We have this problem on all Windows 10 computers. I will check, however. Tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: @IInspectable Does not seem like the right solution. I have checked, however. No improvement.

Comment: I never proposed any solutions. I explained, how assertions are implemented in Visual Studio, and how they can be customized. Have you checked, that there are not Image Execution Options set in the registry, that may interfere with your assertions? (I believe this key is automatically synchronized between 32- and 64-bit hives, but checking both certainly wouldn't hurt.)

Comment: @IInspectable Yes, I have checked. I am will try to debug MS' code and see if I find what the problem is.

Comment: I'm also having this issue.  I'll add that it has something to do with code compiled by Visual Studio 2015, the same code when compiled with Visual Studio 2013 works properly on the same machine.  I was debugging down in the code that corresponds to crtmbox.cpp, however it appears that the binary on my machine is different than the code in the SDK.  (same build number)  I'm able to change some registers with the debugger at opportune times, and get the correct dialog to show up, but I've not yet figured out how I can get it to work without me tweaking registers.

Comment: @MrSlippers Microsoft is ignoring the problem. They have closed my [first](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3107058/assert-crashes-the-application-when-run-without-debugging) bug report as "By Design". I did not receive an answer to the [second](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3115985/common-show-message-box-bug) one.

Comment: I wonder if this has to do with using the 14393 UCRT on a 10240 build of Windows 10?   like the windows half of things is where that developer_information_policy is being set

Comment: I do not recall many details, the general conclusion was that the code in `common_show_message_box` is wrong. I might be wrong; maybe you can have a look at it and confirm it. Meanwhile I have learnt to live with it.

Comment: I just tested my theory on a second machine that is running windows build 14393.  On that machine the assert dialog works properly.  When running the same program on build 10240, it does not work.    I believe that BOTH machines have the 14393 version of the Universal CRT, and that mismatch is causing something to break.  My hunch is that if I update my main machine, the asserts will start working there as well.  I'll probably do that update in teh next few days, been meaning to do it anyways, and then I'll report back.

Comment: @MrSlippers I do not have the freedom of updating my machine. However, my home system has less restrictions (i.e. it gets the latest updates) and it works fine. If I correctly recall, UCRT versions are different.

Comment: I've been able to update my machine, and the issue did NOT go away.  It really appears to be a bug in the 14393 ucrtbased.dll.  In fact, I've since found that my working machine was running the 10240 build of ucrtbased.dll (despite running on 14393 of windows itself).  On that machine I installed the 14393 SDK (and thus the updated ucrtbased.dll).  And now that machine is broken as well.

Comment: Same problem here. After installing Visual Studio 2017 no more assert dialogs, just a process exit. Most likely this is also related the broken runtime that is installed along with VS2017. ucrtbased.dll version 10.0.14393.795

Comment: @QBziZ If you have a Microsoft account, please click the [I can too](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3115985/common-show-message-box-bug) button.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found out it has been fixed in the latest version of the Windows 10 SDK (version 10.0.15063.0) which can be downloaded from 
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk